# работа с наборами записей двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Как реализовать в SQL вот это (очень срочно):

Даны 3 даты заселения и 3 даты выселения (поле может быть и пустым, т. е. неизвестно, когда выселился).

*Пример*: (2007-09-01(засел), 2007-10-01(засел), 2008-09-01(засел), 2010-09-01(высел), пустая дата(высел), 2014-06-30(высел))

**Вопрос**: как сделать, чтобы 2-дату заселения сравнить с 1-выселения, потом 3 -дату заселения сравнить с 2-датой выселения и т.д.?
т.е. каждую следующую дату заселения сравнивать с предыдущей выселения

Comment: 1) это нужно в sql, или можно и в, скажем, php делать? 2) а как сравнивать-то? условия какие? чего ожидать (выяснять) от сравнения?

Comment: >  (очень срочно)
Если заселился в 2007 году, а выселился в 2014, то к чему тогда такая срочность? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если Я вас верно понял у вас в таблице 2 поля
date1 заселения
date2 выселения
нужно в запросе использовать таблицу 3 раза
пример

`select * from 
    table t1,
    table t2,
    table t3
    where t1.tt=t2.tt
    and t1.tt=t3.tt
    and (t1.date1>t2.date2 or t2.date2 is null)
    and t2.date1>t3.date2 or t3.date2 is null)`